# Using Get() with an Array Structure

Tags: c++

Hello I do not understand why my `storms.get(names[a].hurricaneName, 10);` won't work. The program runs with any errors but it does not print out `names[a].hurricaneName`.

[image: This is my programs output]

Also my input file is

```
Fea        287 8 1975 162 185 130 145 168 8 9  8
Josh       199 6 1957 78  36  25  75  86  5 2  2
Malcom     123 4 1995 45  87  63  86  48  4 4  1
Spinny Guy 299 9 1993 186 145 173 145 148 7 10 10
Road Run   391 7 1923 156 185 137 175 156 5 4  4
Hoover     403 5 1946 87  85  87  86  87  2 6  4
Stephen    109 7 1987 146 148 156 146 176 7 5  4
Nick       187 4 1926 186 186 86  85  68  5 4  2
Austin     348 4 1928 86  96  45  83  85  6 2  3
Jerry      394 5 1956 156 145 184 135 134 7 5  1
Jacob      689 8 1945 187 176 136 176 157 5 8  3
Bruce      163 7 1934 156 185 183 54  94  5 2  0
Ronald     483 5 1937 187 165 148 175 164 8 4  8
Billy Bob  189 2 1945 67  86  87  56  64  2 2  8
Caroline   389 5 1987 97  97  57  75  23  5 3  4
Jim Carrey 892 5 1902 145 176 156 185 154 7 4  7
Guillermo  239 7 1916 187 87  76  64  85  3 2  8
Nye        594 5 1974 145 197 184 175 147 4 5  3
Marvin     782 4 1962 87  67  87  88  74  3 5  7
Bugs Bunny 903 7 1973 67  54  184 112 129 7 4  4
Dare Devil 923 7 1973 67  54  184 112 129 7 4  4
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Info
{
    char hurricaneName[11];
    int ID;
    int life;
    int date;
    float avgWindSpeed;
    float avgRainFall;
    int totalTornadoes;
};

int main()
{
    Info names[256];

    ifstream storms;
    storms.open("storms.txt");

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Results.txt");
    outfile << fixed << setprecision(2);


    //This will count how many lines have information in them or are being used.
    int counter = 0;
    while (storms)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        storms.ignore(256,'\n');
    }
    cout << "There are a total of " << counter << " lines being used." << endl;
    //This is the end of that program

    for(int a = 0; a < counter; a++)
    {
        storms.get(names[a].hurricaneName, 10); //This peice of code is suppose to read in the names of each storm which has to be less than 11 characters.
        cout << names[a].hurricaneName;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The main thing that I wanted that piece of code to do would be to eventually when it is finished to print out all the names of the storms. For example `Fea`, `Josh`, `Malcom`, etc.
I would really be grateful if someone could explain what I did wrong or where my error is, but in a way that a beginner can understand.

Comment: The shown code runs a loop that repeatedly reads 10 characters from the input file, after it already read the entire file. Since it already read the entire file, continuing to read anything from the file, from that point on, does not do anything. Which part of this is unclear to you? Remember: your computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. And this is what you told your computer to do.

Comment: Yea I just realized that. It was a logical error. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I had to do to make my code work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Info
{
    char hurricaneName[11];
    int ID;
    int life;
    int date;
    float avgWindSpeed;
    float avgRainFall;
    int totalTornadoes;
};

int main()
{
    Info names[256];

    ifstream storms;
    storms.open("storms.txt");

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Results.txt");
    outfile << fixed << setprecision(2);


    //This will count how many lines have information in them or are being used.
    int counter = 0;
    while (storms)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        storms.ignore(256,'\n');
    }
    cout << "There are a total of " << counter << " lines being used." << endl;
    //This is the end of that program

    storms.clear();
    storms.seekg(0, ios::beg);


    for(int a = 0; a < counter; a++)
    {
        storms.get(names[a].hurricaneName, 10); //This peice of code is suppose to read in the names of each storm which has to be less than 11 characters.
        cout << names[a].hurricaneName;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The only thing that I had to add was `storms.clear();
    storms.seekg(0, ios::beg);` after my counter block to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem that you are at the end of the input file when you start reading in the names. You may want to use `storms.seekg(0);` or do both counting and getting in the same loop.

But even if you do it, as @SamVarshavchik has said, you would get garbage values since you don't ignore the numbers after the storms, so you would put out something like `Fea      287` or so.

I would recommend:

```cpp
std::string tmp;
int index = 0;
while(std::getline(storms, tmp))
{
    std::stringstream ss(tmp);
    ss >> names[index].hurricaneName;
    ++i
}
```

At the end, `index` will be the number of lines read.